# BizTalk Rule Composer does not update rules after adding new vocabularies

Tags: schema, biztalk, rule-engine, business-rules, biztalk-2013

I inherited a BizTalk application that is using Rule Composer to set up policies. I introduced new vocabularies and added new rules, however the new rules does not take effect after deploying the policies to BizTalk. I can see that the old vocabularies still reference the old schema created by the former developer, and I can't change the path. I am very green in BizTalk and have no experience with rule composer. Any advice?

Comment: Yes,  the old vocabs would not change, are you sure you have not only both Published and Deployed the new vocabs and policies, also restarting the Rule Engine Publishing service helps it take effect quicker.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, I did so, but still nothing changed.